# How to force to top the div but using absolute position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope you will get my point. Sorry for the confusing title.
But here's my scenario

I have some list of content on my page and it is very long. Now in some of the info there is some links that when you click there will be a hidden information that will reveal upon clicking.

Now my problem is when the hidden information is shown I need to scroll up my page in order to view the upper part. Because in the top part I have my close button. What I want is the hidden information will start from the top but will not affect the overlapping information under it. Meaning the content under should be stay the same. Because if I used the scroll to top function after the showing of the content it will scroll to top.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="talent-content" class="container n-p-b">

    <div class="col-xs-12 main_title">
        <div class="about_header container">
            <h5 class="text-right">
                STAFFS
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- START STAFF LIST -->

    <!-- staff 1 -->
    <div class="row staff_row n-p-b n-m-b" style="margin-top: 0px;" id="service-row-1">
        <div class="container-fluid n-p-b">
            <img src="catalog/view/theme/fx3cafe/image/staff/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-img" />
            <div class="staff_detail col-xs-12">

                <h4 class="colorhover">NAMNE 1 <small>Position 1</small></h4>

                <!-- show the hidden content -->
                <a href="javascript:;" class="pull-right talent_description_link" data-id="1">view more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- hidden content -->
        <div class="extra_description" id="talent-showcase-info-1">
            <!-- here's some content that may be long -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- staff 2 -->
    <div class="row staff_row n-p-b n-m-b" style="margin-top: 0px;" id="service-row-2">
        <div class="container-fluid n-p-b">
            <img src="catalog/view/theme/fx3cafe/image/staff/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-img" />
            <div class="staff_detail col-xs-12">

                <h4 class="colorhover">NAME 2 <small>Position 2</small></h4>

                <!-- show the hidden content -->
                <a href="javascript:;" class="pull-right talent_description_link" data-id="1">view more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- hidden content -->
        <div class="extra_description" id="talent-showcase-info-2">
            <!-- here's some content that may be long -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- staff 3 -->
    <div class="row staff_row n-p-b n-m-b" style="margin-top: 0px;" id="service-row-3">
        <div class="container-fluid n-p-b">
            <img src="catalog/view/theme/fx3cafe/image/staff/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-img" />
            <div class="staff_detail col-xs-12">

                <h4 class="colorhover">NAME 3 <small>Position 3</small></h4>

                <!-- show the hidden content -->
                <a href="javascript:;" class="pull-right talent_description_link" data-id="1">view more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- hidden content -->
        <div class="extra_description" id="talent-showcase-info-3">
            <!-- here's some content that may be long -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- STAFF IS 20 ROWS OF TOTAL... -->

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.talent_description_link').on('click', function() {
    var $id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#talent-showcase-info-' + $id).show().removeClass('animated slideOutRight ');
    $('#talent-showcase-info-' + $id).show().addClass('animated slideInRight'); 
    //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
});

$('.closeThumbnails').on('click', function() {
    $('.extra_description').show().removeClass('animated slideInRight');
    $('.extra_description').show().addClass('animated slideOutRight '); 
    // $('.talent-showcase').fadeOut()
});
```

**CSS (SASS)**

```
/** STAFFS **/
#talent-content {
    position: relative;
    .main_title {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        span.divider { color: $lightgray; }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            &.prev-page { color: $lightgray; }
            &.current-page { color: $hovercolorlight; font-weight: bold; }
            &:hover {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
    }

    .about_header {
        border: 0px;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        background: $verylightgray;
        h5 {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    }

    .staff_row {
        .staff_detail {
            padding: 10px;
            h4,small {
                color: $hovercolor;
            }
            small { 
                font-size: 12px;
                color: $verylightgray; 
                &:before {
                    content: "(";
                }
                &:after {
                    content: ")";
                }
            }
            p {
                text-align: justify;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            a {
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
        }
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        .extra_description {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: $darkcolor;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin-top: 40px;
            z-index: 9;
            padding: 15px;
            .closeThumbnails {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            h4 {
                color: $hovercolor;
            }
            .date_year {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            .history_list {
                text-align: left;
                ul {
                    list-style: none;
                    li {
                        color: #fff;
                        font-size: 12px;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Can you help me with this?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/nu3fc6d3/6/

Comment: Can you post a working snippet demonstrating your problem?

Comment: @void Ok I will try  to create one.

Comment: here's my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/nu3fc6d3/6/

Comment: sounds like $(document).scroll() & elem.offset().top could help here.